# Deprecated: WP_User_Query was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 5.9.0! who is deprecated

Tags: wordpress

Deprecated: WP_User_Query was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 5.9.0! who is deprecated. Use capability instead. in public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5600

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 4):

You must have a `get_user()` function with parameter 'who'. It has been depreciated in 5.9. Use it as follows instead:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'    => 'post_count',
    'order'      => 'DESC',
    'capability' => array( 'edit_posts' ),
);
 
// Capability queries were only introduced in WP 5.9.
if ( version_compare( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], '5.9', '<' ) ) {
    $args['who'] = 'authors';
    unset( $args['capability'] );
}
 
$authors = get_users( $args );
```

More info: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/01/05/new-capability-queries-in-wordpress-5-9/